# how to open port to the world

Tags: networking, services, port-forwarding

I have installed postgresql (or any other service for that matter) on ubuntu 14.04.1.LTS
I can start postgres and it is running. 
It accepts connections on port 5432.

```
This is my netstat output:
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432               :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

I want to connect from a different computer in the same network to this postgres instance.
Which will not work as it is only listening on localhost.

What do I need to do to make it listen on 0.0.0.0:5432 (the rest of the world?)?

Comment: This would be helpfull.http://serverfault.com/questions/336596/opening-port-5432-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `postgresql.conf` and change `listen_address`:

```
listen_addresses='*'
```